# Django filter tag not working: AttributeError at / 'str' object has no attribute 'filter_function

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

According to the Document model below, the 'document.upload.name' in the template will display like "user_NAME/smile.jpg". 
I want to split the "user_NAME/smile.jpg" by '/'. So in the template, it will only display "smile.jpg". 
I use the 'value.split' in the filter of 'upload_extras'. but the error was: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter_function'.

this is the template:

```
<td><a href="{{ document.upload.url }}" target="_blank">{{ 
document.upload.name|filename_extract }}</a></td>
```

this is my function in upload_extras.py

```
#upload_extras.py
from Django import template 
register =template.Library

@register.filter('filename_extract')
def filename_extract(value):
  '''extract the file name from the upload_to_path'''
       folder, filename = value.split('/')
       return filename
```

And the last is the model:

```
 # Create your models here.
 def upload_to_path(instance, filename):
     return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.username, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
     uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     upload = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_path)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your custom filter in the template.

At the top of your template, add

```
{% load upload_extras %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have post the trace on the bottom

Comment: in which folder have you placed upload_extras.py?

Comment: it is under 'templatetags' folder in my 'upload' app

Comment: I solved it, it is very wired. because I change function name to 'filename' from 'filename_extract'. it is working now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter('filename')
def filename(value):
    folder, filename=value.split("/")
    return filename
```

I changed the function name from 'filename_extract' to 'filename'. it is working now. this is a very wired situation.